# CSS displays differently in french and in english navs

Tags: html, css

I have a french website that detects the language of the nav to display french or english.

On my html, I have an input and a button inside a div. I was astonished to see that the input and the button where horizontally aligned in the french but it is not the case for the english version, although the html and the css are the same ! 
The weird thing is that in french the input css propriety of left-floating input is red but it is not the case in english. Could someone explain ?

Best,
Newben

Comment: Just on case anybody knows if there are different ways to read css relatively to navs language rules  !

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP to load different CSS stylesheets depending on the user's language detected.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample code, it's hard to tell what the layout problem is. It sounds like since the two different languages (English and French) use up different amounts of space on your site, they're jostling other elements around. For example, if a French sentence is longer than an English, then it may use up more of the site's width, thus pushing other elements into the wrong places. If this is the problem, you may be able to fix it by using fixed-width `<div>` tags, etc.
Another possible cause of the layout problem is if letters are being used that are not part of your page's set character encoding.

Comment: For sure I have verified carefully the size of the div depending on the length of the sentences in different langages. But thanks, for the idea using php to load different css styling depending on the user's nav langage.

Comment: If you're still having a problem, you can post some HTML and CSS causing the issue. Let me know if you do so.